# How do I display the price of my Coin/Token in the TronLink wallet

Tags: cryptocurrency, tron, tronlink

**PS: I offer my full apologies if the content of the question is not appropriate for the site**

My problem, in a nutshell, is as follows, I have a coin/token in the Tron network, the latter of which can be found on the CoinGecko website

However, unfortunately, when the coin appears in the TronLink wallet, the following symbol “-” always appears near it in the price, which means that its price is unknown.

I tried searching the internet to find any possible way to show its price in the wallet and unfortunately without any result, unfortunately, TronLink wallet support is very weak.

Is there a solution to that?

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a bit late but tronlink among many other crypto wallets use coinmarketcap api in order to get token/coin prices.
so listing your token inside coinmarketcap is a must.

Answer (score 0):

Tokens price may not be visible on trolinkpro wallet or defi wallet because liquidity and volumes my be lower than threshold required by coinmarketcap. If the token get listed on any exchange the price then become visible because the token get access to good liquidity.